# C# Loading an exe on a file share

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a program on a Citrix VM located at `\\site.local\shares\Agent_console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe /env=PROD`

I am currently using the code below and it is stating the following

```
private void button13Chromatix_Launcher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"\\plumbedford.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe",
                  "/Env=PROD");
}
```

But that fails with the following error:

> Unable to access Agent Console XML network share. Try again?

This is a desktop shortcut that works using the same directory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you copy the exact string in the Process.Start() call into Windows Explorer, does it work?

Comment: It attempts to load without that /Env=PROD argument so the syntax is wrong?

Comment: I have never had to code a click to open a network share with an argument tagged at the end.  So I am clearly missing a step here to perform that argument correctly in c#?

Comment: `But that fails`: please describe exactly what happens. Error message, observed behavior, ...

Comment: I have this updated in the comments below but here is what is occuring now:

Update to the issue: The current code I have is: Process.Start(@"\\plumbedford.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_‌​Launch\AC_Launcher.e‌​xe", "/Env=PROD"); Still getting an error but different one now: Error: Unable to access Agent Console XML network share Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a literal string (with an `@` prefix), to ensure that backslashes are not misinterpreted.
It also looks like you have some typos in the location.

Try this:

```
Process.Start(@"\\site.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe", "/env=PROD");
```

Comment: It seems to be failing at the /env=PROD" part

Comment: I do not think this is the correct syntax for that argument.

Comment: This directory is pulled from the desktop shortcut on the VM.  I am sure that /env=PROD is not coded correctly in C#..  Suggestions?

Comment: Current code now used but still failing:
Process.Start(@"\\site.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe /Env=PROD");

Comment: I will give that shot tomorrow and see if it works.  I will update if pass or fail tomorrow in the AM.  Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the code provided and it still failed to load the share.

Comment: I tried the code provided and it still failed to load the share.
Code used:
Process.Start(@"\\plumbedford.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe", "/Env=PROD");
Error: Unable to access Agent Console XML network share. Try again?
Any other suggestions I can try would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update to the issue:

The current code I have is:

Process.Start(@"\\plumbedford.local\shares\Agent_Console\AC_Launch\AC_Launcher.exe", "/Env=PROD");

Still getting an error but different one now:

Error: Unable to access Agent Console XML network share

Suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer with the code and error message.  Thank you.